# fluent-bit: set es index parameter from value of index in log data

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, fluent-bit

I want to set the value of the Index parameter of ES ouput in fluent-bit with the value of index field in the incoming logdata. Im unable to set this in fluent-bit

The application writes the log to a file on kubernetes node that looks like this, which is in json format

```json
{"_id":"3137","completed":false,"index":"head_app_log","index_pattern":"app_log_2023-09-13_*","lang":["en"],"user":"63d93c8202acb900094f099e"}
{"_id":"3137-0","index":"app_log_2023-09-13_en","msg":"Started executing","parent":null}
{"_id":"3137","completed":true,"index":"apc_head_app_log","index_pattern":"apc_app_log_2023-09-13_*","lang":["en"],,"user":"63d93c8202acb900094f099e"}
```

From the log, i want to pass the value of the field "index" to the output plugin

```yaml
[INPUT]
    Name tail
    Path /var/log/app-log-elastic/app_*.log
    multiline.parser docker, cri
    Tag app_log.*
    Mem_Buf_Limit 200MB
    Read_from_Head true
    Skip_Long_Lines Off
    Buffer_Chunk_Size 50M
    Buffer_Max_Size 100M

[OUTPUT]
    Name es
    Match app_log.*
    Host 127.0.0.1
    Port 9200
    HTTP_User elastic
    HTTP_Passwd XXXXXXXXXX
    Logstash_Format Off
    Index $index
```

I could not find a way to dynamically pass the value to index parameter. I do not want to use the enable logstash as this is already in json format and structured in elastic using index_templates

There exists an index_template in elastic for both the indexes, head_app_log and app_log_2023-09-13_en

Can anyone help me here ??.

I could not find anything related to this on fluent-bit docs. In fluentd however, this whole parameter is optional in the elastic output plugin.